# swiftUI: Animation messed up when hide component by using offset()

Tags: animation, swiftui

[image]

As you can see the gif, when I try to hide the buttonPanel, the animation is messed up.
Here is the generic button

```
struct GenericButtonViews<T: View>: View {
    
    @StateObject var model: CoreMLViewModel
    var name: String
    var symbol: T
    let action: () -> Void
    let buttonType: ButtonStyle
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button {
            action()
        } label: {
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                symbol
                Text(name)
                    .foregroundColor(Color("theme"))
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 3)
            .scaleEffect(model.isAudioRecording && buttonType == .styled ? 1.25 : 1)
            .opacity(model.isAudioRecording  && buttonType == .styled ? 0.5 : 1)
            .animation(model.isAudioRecording  && buttonType == .styled ? Animation.linear(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : .none)
        }        
    }
}

enum ButtonStyle {
    case normal, styled
}
```

my re-useable button with button type enum set to .styled, implemented in ButtonPanel.swift

```
GenericButtonViews(
   model: model,
   name: "", symbol: ButtonContent(symbol: model.isAudioRecording ? "micro" : "micro-off"),
   action: {
            model.isAudioRecording.toggle()
            model.toggleEngine()
   },
   buttonType: .styled)
```

implementation of ButtonPanel in MainView.swift. The logic here is the panel will be hidden out of the screen when the show/hide button is tapped.

```
ButtonPanelView(model: model, width: geo.size.width)
  .offset(y: !model.showingBtnPanel ? 0 : geo.size.height)
  .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
  .animation(.spring(blendDuration: 0.25))
```

I've tried a few ways but this still happening. Any suggestion would be much appreaciate!

Comment: I assume you need to link *every* animation's value to its triggering state, because they conflict somewhere.

Comment: @Asperi it works, could you please explain to me why this happens or link to any documentation that I can read more about it? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Asperi for helping me, I basicall added value: model.isAudioRecording to any .animation involved and it works like a charm